# Extracting a nested table from a polars dataframe with associated id

Tags: python-polars

I have a response from a `graphql` endpoint containing a list of entities. Each returned entity contains embedded related entities.

```py
df = pl.from_dicts([
    {"id":0, "z":0.0, "right": [{"x":0.0, "y":0.0}]},
    {"id":1, "z":1.0, "right": [{"x":0.0, "y":0.0}, {"x":1.0, "y":1.0}]},
    {"id":2, "z":2.0, "right": [{"x":0.0, "y":0.0}, {"x":1.0, "y":1.0}, {"x":2.0, "y":2.0}]},
])
print(df.schema)
```

```
OrderedDict([('id', Int64), ('z', Float64), ('right', List(Struct({'x': Float64, 'y': Float64})))])
```

I want to split into `left` and `right` DataFrames where left consists of ("id", "z") and right ("id", "x", "y").

The following partially achieves what I need:

```py
left = df.select("id", "z")
left

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ z   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 0.0 │
│ 1   ┆ 1.0 │
│ 2   ┆ 2.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

```py
right = df.select(pl.col("right").list.explode()).unnest('right')
right

shape: (6, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

But I need the associated `id` fields from the original dataframe, i.e.

```py
right = right.with_columns(id = pl.Series([0,1,1,2,2,2]))
right

shape: (6, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   ┆ id  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 0   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 1   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 1   │
│ 0.0 ┆ 0.0 ┆ 2   │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 2   │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out myself, I actually thought I'd already tried this but on 2nd attempt it worked

```py
df.select("id", "right").explode('right').unnest('right')
```